# While Yolo darknet training, several images cannot loaded error(?)

Tags: deep-learning, detection, yolo, darknet

[Darknet YOLO training screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsnlC.png)

Do you know the reason?
How can I fix this?

Comment: probably something wrong in your training.txt, like image path

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways it may happen:

1. Image may be corrupted (check it by typing -> `file filename.jpg`)
2. Image file name should not have two dots like : **imagename.train.jpg** (change filename to **imagename_train.jpg**)
3. Image file name should not contain **raw** word, darknet will replace **raw** word with draw , so the image file names and xml file names mis-match

Please share your image file names, so i can say where the mistake happened.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
After reunzip image files it solved^^.